# Inside cmd batch script recursive for loop, get matched files path relative to script file

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe, script

I am trying to achieve this by substracting `%~dp0` from `%%~dpa`, where `%%a` is the for loop variable. If anyone is aware of a better way to do this, please advise.

My code is as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    set "file=%%~dpa"
    set "scriptpath=%~dp0"
    set "result=%!file!:!scriptpath!=%"
    echo !result!
    echo !scriptpath!
)

pause
```

This results in:

```
D:\path\to script\file\=
D:\path\to script\file\
```

I've played with these around for hours and can't get it to work. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please give some examples of before and after filenames.

Comment: FIlenames are irrelevant. Even if I have something like `file.mp4` inside a `folder` subfolder, teh results are the same. So I'm definitely not doing something right. Did you close my question? I think it is formualted quite properly and complete. I'm only asking how to list those relative paths. Please reopen it.

Comment: Why don't you just use %%~na.  Type `help call` for a list of all the %%~ options.  There are 10 options.

Comment: @cup I want the relative path(from the script) to the files, not their filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I get matching files with the path relative to the script file path?

You were almost there ...

Use the following batch file (I've commented out the lines in your script that were in the wrong place or incorrect):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "scriptpath=%~dp0"
for /r %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    rem set "file=%%~dpa"
    set "file=%%a"
    rem set "scriptpath=%~dp0"
    rem set "result=%!file!:!scriptpath!=%"
    call set "result=%%file:%scriptpath%=%%"
    echo !result!
    echo !scriptpath!
)
```

Please read [CMD Variable edit replace - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) for an explanation of why `call` is needed when there is a variable who's **value** you are trying to replace.

Example:

```
F:\test>dir /b /s *.mp4
F:\test\3.mp4
F:\test\2.mp4
F:\test\1.mp4
F:\test\sub 2\1.mp4
F:\test\sub 2\2.mp4
F:\test\sub 2\3.mp4
F:\test\sub 1\1.mp4
F:\test\sub 1\2.mp4
F:\test\sub 1\3.mp4

F:\test>test
3.mp4
F:\test\
2.mp4
F:\test\
1.mp4
F:\test\
sub 2\1.mp4
F:\test\
sub 2\2.mp4
F:\test\
sub 2\3.mp4
F:\test\
sub 1\1.mp4
F:\test\
sub 1\2.mp4
F:\test\
sub 1\3.mp4
F:\test\

F:\test>
```

Comment: I've had to switch back to `set "file=%%~dpa"`, because I wanted only the relative path, not including the filename. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

---

- Folder tree:

```bat
F:\2021-SU\Q1635032> tree /f /a|find/v "Q635032.cmd"

Folder PATH listing for volume 2nd
Volume serial number is FACF-B9ED
F:.
|   file 00.mp4
|
+---other sub dir
|   |   other file 00.mp4
|   |
|   \---sub dir 1
|           other file 01.mp4
|
\---some sub dir
    |   some file 00.mp4
    |
    \---sub dir 1
            some file 01.mp4
```

---

An option without variables, which runs only once per folder that contains .mp4

- To list only the folder name:

```bat
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" && for /r /d %%i in (.
    )do dir/b/a "%%~i\*.mp4" >nul && echo=.\%%~nxi
```

---

**1.** Go to your bat folder: **`cd/d "%~dp0"`**

**2.** Loop all folders recursively : **`for /r /d %%i in (.)do ...`**

**3.** In each folder, check if there is mp4 in it: **`dir /b/a "%%~i\*.mp4"`**

**4.** Omit errors if there is no mp4 in it: ... **`dir ...  >nul`**

**5.** If **`dir .mp4 return 0`**, use an operator to execute **`echo\ Folder_Name`**:  **`&& echo=.\%%~nxi`**

- **Obs.: 1** These options did not list repeated folder names, when the folder contains more than one mp4 file

---

- Results/Output:

```bat
F:\2021-SU\Q1635032> Q635032.cmd
.\Q1635032
.\other sub dir
.\sub dir 1
.\some sub dir
.\sub dir 1
```

---

- To list the relative path of the folder:

```bat
@echo off && cd/d "%~dp0"
 
subst .: "%~dp0" && .: && for /r /d %%i in (.)do (
     dir /b/a "%%~i\*.mp4" >nul && echo=.%%~pnxi )

cd /d "%~dp0" & subst /d .:
```

---

**1.** Go to your bat folder: **`cd/d "%~dp0"`**

**2.** Assign a virtual drive to your folder: **`subst .: "%~dp0"`**

**3.** Enter the created virtual drive: **`.. && .:`**

**4.** Loop all folders recursively : **`for /r /d %%i in (.)do ...`**

**5.** In each folder, check if there is mp4 in it: **`dir/b/a "%%~i\*.mp4"`**

**6.** Omit errors if there is no mp4 in it: ... **`dir ...  >nul`**

**7.** If **`dir .mp4 return 0`**, use an operator to execute **`echo..`** :  **`&& echo=.%%~pnxi`**

**8.** Return to the original dive/folder, exit the virtual drive: **`cd /d "%~dp0"`**

**9.** The virtual drive created on the run, is no longer needed, remove it: **`subst /d .:`**

- **Obs.: 2** The virtual unit **`.:`**, will not be available and capable of interaction in the graphical user interface, thus avoiding interference from the user when the script is running:

---

- Results/Output:

```bat
F:\2021-SU\Q1635032> Q635032.cmd
.\
.\other sub dir
.\other sub dir\sub dir 1
.\some sub dir
.\some sub dir\sub dir 1
```

---

**Obs.: 3**  About the **`For /R /D`** loop command:

- ```bat
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```bat
  The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

---

To suppress the root folder/working directory, to list only the folder name, such as:

```bat
F:\2021-SU\Q1635032> Q635032.cmd
.\Q1635032
.\other sub dir
.\sub dir 1
.\some sub dir
.\sub dir 1
```

You can make use of a mixed option from the previous two:

```bat
@echo off && cd/d "%~dp0" 

subst .: "%~dp0" && .: && for /r /d %%i in (.)do ( 
     dir /b /a "%%~i\*.mp4">nul && echo=.\%%~nxi )
    
cd/d "%~dp0" && subst /d .:
```

---

**Obs.: 4** - Using a `For` loop you can expand your variable:

```bat
    %~i   - expands %i removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fi  - expands %i to a fully qualified path file/dir name only
    %~ni  - expands %i to a file/dir name only
    %~xi  - expands %i to a file/dir extension only
    
    %%~nxi => expands %%~i to a file/dir name and extension
```

- ```bat
  Use the FOR variable syntax replacement:
      %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
      %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
      %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  ```
- ```bat
  The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
      %~pnI       - expands %I to a path and file name only
      %~pnxI      - expands %I to a path, file name and extension only
  ```

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[Subst](https://ss64.com/nt/subst.html)**
  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
  - **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**
  - **[Redirection in bat file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
  - **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**